# JAD file must reference the JAR file

Tags: java-me, jar, nokia, midp-2.0, jad

While trying to publish a java app to the ovi nokia store there's an error - "JAD file must reference the JAR file". What can cause this problem if removing jar file and recompiling project doesn't help?

Comment: does your jad contain attribute `MIDlet-Jar-URL`?

Comment: gnat, thank you very much, I renamed both jar and jad files but MIDlet-Jar-URL contained the old name, you can make your comment as an answer.

Comment: you're welcome - I made comment into answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per my reading of documentation in [Sun/Oracle tutorial](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/learn/midp/lifecycle/) error message like you received might indicate that something wrong is going on with your jad attribute `MIDlet-Jar-URL`:

> ...The JAR file will be installed from the location `MIDlet-Jar-URL`. The size of the download must agree with the `MIDlet-Jar-Size` value...